# Handling Form Recognizer Response Code 429

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I'm currently using the Document Intelligence SDK and it's hitting the maximum Concurrent limit in the production.
As per microsoft's documentation :
I need to implement

> an exponential backoff on the GET analyze response request. By using a progressively longer wait time between retries for consecutive error responses, for example a 2-5-13-34 pattern of delays between requests.

I can get the http status of the request using the method **GetRawResponse()**

My question is what response I will get when I'm getting Response Code 429()

I'm trying to get the result and response in the following way:

```
try
{
    var operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(
    WaitUntil.Completed,
    MODEL_REF,
    fileUri,
    null,
    cancellationToken);

    var rawResponse = operation.GetRawResponse();

    if (rawResponse.Status == 429)
    {
        //Implement exponential backoff
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"MEssage: {ex.Message} | StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
}
```

My question is,

1.What will the operation value will be when it's getting 429 response code
from Microsoft
like:
operation.HasCompleted //should this be false?
operation.HasValue; //should this be false?

I couldn't find any refereence of what will be operation's response when the httpStatus is 429

2.The above code is implemented assuming the http Status code will be available in GetRawResponse()
method, not in Exception. Is the assumption is right?

Comment: you can check this thread for details regarding 429 issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58124658/httperror-429-client-error-too-many-requests-for-url-in-python-w-azure-dev